# What if you spin a fluid in one direction at center and at the same time opposite direction at outside?

Tags: rotation, vortex

This question keeps me busy for couple of weeks. To be clear,

If I put a fluid into a blender and start it, it will spin in one direction. This will create a small vortex.

What if I am able to spin the container that holds the fluid in opposite direction to the center at the same time with the inner spinning?

The reason I am asking is to find what happens if the core and earth rotate in opposite directions. will it change mantle flow, change the magnetism or gravity?

Comment: The answer to this very much depends on which parametric regimes you're interested in exploring (eg which reynolds number), as well as the exact geometry of the configuration in question, so you'll have to be more specific. one example of flow in rotating cylinders is the well known taylor-couette flow. you can get started by looking here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%E2%80%93Couette_flow

Comment: Thank you Nick P for the reply. My question is not about the Taylor-Couette flow. a fluid will rotate the same direction with the rotational force. but what if the cup that holds the fluid rotates in opposite direction? As an example, if I stir a coffee with a spoon, coffee will rotate in the same direction with the spoon. what if I spin the cup at the same time in the opposite direction to the spoon with the same speed?

Comment: You get the kind of turbulence which leads to things like the red spot of Jupiter, I suspect.

Comment: From what I know, the great spot rotates because of the flow on its boundaries. And it rotates the same way